# Java - Arrays binarySearch returning unexpected result after custom sort

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

Here is the simple piece of code that I build to understand `Arrays.binarySearch`. But it is returning a result which I did not even expect.

```
    String[] c = {"A", "Z", "B"};
    Arrays.sort(c, new MyNewComparator1()); //Z, B, A
    System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(c, "Z")); //0
    System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(c, "S")); //-2 based on insertion point
    System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(c, "N")); //Unpredicable result we can expect
```

Here is my custom Comparator

```
class MyNewComparator1 implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s2.compareTo(s1);
    }
}
```

Result I am expecting `0, -2, Unpredictable`

But the result it is returning `-4, -4, -4`

Can someone please help me to understand why it is returning `-4` for all the search?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't know what `Comparator` you've used to sort your list.  Try using the overload with `Arrays.binarySearch(T[], T, Comparator<T>)`.  Returns the results you expect (although I think `"N"` would just return `-2` as well...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the Javadoc states, your array must be:

> The array must be  sorted into ascending order according to the
>   **natural ordering of its elements (as by the `sort(Object [])` method)**
>   prior to making this call.

The `sort(Object [])` method that the above refers to clarifies:

> Sorts the specified array of objects into **ascending order**, according
>   to the natural ordering of its elements.

You need to sort in **ascending order** but you are sorting in **descending** order.

You need to change your comparator to make it sort in **ascending** order:

```
class MyNewComparator1 implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareTo(s2); // <-- swap s1 and s2
    }
}
```

---

There is an alternative solution. You can redefine what **ascending** *means* by passing your own Comparator to the `binarySearch` method call as the last argument. If you do that, then don't change the comparator - leave it as you originally posted it. But change the `binarySearch` method calls:

```
MyNewComparator1 comparator = new MyNewComparator1();
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(c, "Z", comparator)); // 0
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(c, "S", comparator)); // -2 based on insertion point
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(c, "N", comparator)); // Unpredicable result we can expect
```